# Question about decltype and `std::vector::operator[]`

Tags: c++, c++11

Since there are two overloading functions for `std::vector::operator[]`, one returns a reference, and the other one returns a const reference.

Why the type of `reg_auid` is `char&` other than `const char&`, which is indcated by `vscode`?

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> data_array{100};

    const int IDX = 1;

    //why the type of reg_auid is char& other than const char&
    decltype(data_array[IDX]) reg_auid = data_array[IDX]; 
}
```

Comment: Why should it be `const char&`?  You haver a vector of `char`, not `const char`

Comment: note that `operator[]` is overloaded for `std::vector`: `reference operator[] (size_type n);` and `const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const;`. Most likely whatever extension you're using in vscode for C++ thinks (erroneously) that the const overload gets called.

Comment: `data_array[IDX] = some_char` would not compile if `data_array[IDX]` returned a `const char&`.

Comment: @Turtlefight `vscode` tells me that the `const` one is used other than the `non-const` one.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you so much. I see. Since `data_array` is a non-const `vector`, so the non-const overloading one is called. Am I right?

Comment: @John you are right.  You can deduce this because [the version that returns a const reference is also a const member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Comment: @John Yes.  The only time a const member function is used on a non-const object is when there is no non-const overload of said function.

Comment: @John the non-const overload gets called. And if vscode reports that `reg_auid` is `const char&` then whatever extension you're using in vscode for C/C++ intellisense (vscode doesn't come with a preinstalled one, and there are multiple such extensions) didn't deduce correctly which of the two would be called - so it would a bug in that extension. That's wat i tried to convey with my comment, but i guess i failed at that :D